# Remove Nested array within pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a .mat file to a pandas DataFrame but the structure of the .mat file is making it difficult to unravel.  Currently, the DataFrame looks like this

```
                          A
2008-01-02                [1]
2008-01-03                [2]
2008-01-04                [3]
2008-01-07                [4]
2008-01-08                [5]
```

It looks like the values contained within each column are contained within their own array? .dtype is returning object.  I eventually want to aggregate my columns but since they are not numeric I'm not able to perform numeric function calls. Any ideas on how to remove the values from the array structure while retaining DataFrame structure?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly, each entry is an element that is contained in a Python list, and you would like to take the element out of the list so that each entry is a scalar.

One way you could do this is with the [`df.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) function. Note that this function works on the entire dataframe

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0]) # If same operation is to be used on all columns
```

If you only want to perform the transformation on some of the columns, you could use [`series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) instead:

```
for some columns:
    df['column name'] = df['column name'].map(lambda x: x[0])
```

In either case, you may have to change the `dtype` of the columns afterwards to be able to work with them; changing from list to single element, the `object dtype` of the columns may be preserved. If this is the case, you can use:

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].astype([new type])
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to apply a operation on the column of the dataframe.

You will need to define the `function` then pass it to the `apply` method, depending on what type of the `object` is. For example, if it's a list, you may want to select the first item, if it's a string, you may want to extract and convert the number.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
unnested_lst = []
for col in df.columns:
    unnested_lst.append(df[col].apply(pd.Series).stack())
result = pd.concat(unnested_lst, axis=1, keys=df.columns)
result
                            A
2008-01-02     0            1
2008-01-03     0            2
2008-01-04     0            3
2008-01-07     0            4
2008-01-08     0            5
```

Not sure how to remove the index column of zeros. Any ideas?